# \newenvironment not a simple substitution?

Tags: tables, environments, substitution

I have two versions of the same document, one using `\begin{inner}\end{inner}` to substitute in the environment `inner` and the other with the body of `inner` substituted in manually. The first one triggers an error, and the other works as expected. Here's the first one:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\newenvironment{outerx}
    {
        \noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm} | c |}
    }
    {   
        \end{tabular}
    }
\newenvironment{inner}
    {
        dsfsdf & dssdf
    }
    {
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{outerx}{dsfsdsfd}

\begin{inner}{dsfsdf}
\end{inner}

\end{outerx}

\end{document}
```

This fails with this error message:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@endpbox ...finalstrut \@arstrutbox \par \egroup
                                              \hfil
l.20 \begin{inner}
                  {dsfsdf}
```

Whereas the following works just fine:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\newenvironment{outerx}
    {
        \noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm} | c |}
    }
    {   
        \end{tabular}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{outerx}{dsfsdsfd}

        dsfsdf & dssdf

\end{outerx}

\end{document}
```

Does this mean `\newenvironment` isn't just a simple textual substitution? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code does work by doing a substitution, but you are being caught out by the fact there is *additional* material that `\begin` and `\end` add here to make environments work. In particular, a LaTeX environment forms a group. So you have the equivalent of

```
\begin{outerx}
  \begingroup a & \endgroup b
\end{outerx}
```

which will give the same error: groups cannot span tabular cells. (A cell is itself a group structure in TeX.) So you can't use an environment here: you'll need something like

```
\newcommand*\inner{ dsfsdf & dssdf}
\begin{outerx}
  \inner
\end{outerx}
```

(Handling `&` tokens is particularly 'fun' in TeX: hiding them in macros is tricky.)